# unable to create an archive of any form on Mac OS X, GUI or terminal, all fail

Tags: macos, find, acl, chmod, chown

### Unable to create slightly large a disk Image with Disk Utility

Hello, I have two home directories of friends whose computers died but I was able to save the data from their ~/username successfully.  None were disk errors, but other hardware according to Apple's Hardware Test tool. I have *high confidence* the data is safe and not corrupt.

Usually I will open Disk Utility and select *File -> New -> Create Disk Image From Folder*, within that I select *"Compressed"* and have tried both with encryption and without. It takes some time, likely due to reading and writing from the same media, but eventually it will fail, silently.

I watch in the Terminal with a loop that runs `ls -la` so I can see the file size of the .dmg grow.

This is my command, it should be harmless and low CPU usage:

```
while true; do ls -la | grep jake\.dmg; sleep 60; done
```

when it hits around 95% it *silently stops*, the .dmg it was working on *disappears*?, it is deleted from all I can tell, as when I run a backup, I only find small amounts of data to backup, so there appear to be no hidden file(s) that are building up.  If there are, they are in /tmp somewhere, and will get nuked on reboot, but I see no multi GB files, and a `find` of all files larger than 1GB fails to find anything related, and that is with the `find sudo /` being my starting command.

I am wondering, can I use tar with the gzip option?  Or will that ruin the meta data, resource forks, data forks, and other hidden file data?  At least I may get better debug info. Or maybe use `hdiutil` with the -verbose/-debug verbs. Or has the tar version on Mac OS X been made safe for such operations.  I know that even to this day, rsync, a great backup tool, still needs a patch and recompile to make a true bit for bit copy.

The logs that I watch tell me little.

### Currently, figuring this out would satisfy a curiosity that so far, asking around, no one has been able to answer…

An operation I was trying in the Finder, which has me completely baffled, is I made a new directory called "working", and started to drag and drop folders from one friends archive into it.  For example, I tried to move "Music" into "working".  Basically, trying to move the entire contents of the top level folders of a home directory into the "working" folder.  All these files reside on my computer, on the local disk.

Something like this:

```
$cd ~/Documents/friends
$pwd
> /Users/me/Documents/friends
$mkdir quicktest
$ls -la
 >drwxr-xr-x@ 10 me  staff  340 Aug 22 05:44 jake
 >drwxr-xr-x@ 11 me  staff  374 Aug  5 00:11 amber
 >drwxr-xr-x   2 me  staff   68 Aug 23 21:00 quicktest
$mv ~/Documents/friends/jake/* quicktset/*
```

Just as in the Finder, it will ask me for an admin password.  `ls -la@` shows each of the "users" main parent folder having a hidden attribute of "com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags", which I can delete with xattr -d "com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags", though I don't see why I would need to.

As a side note, the asking for a password is a request to authenticate me to "*copy*" the files.  All I want to do is "*move*" them.  Moments ago, I tried on a directory that does not have the trailing + ACL flag and while not asked for a password, a copy was started, which I cancelled, though I few made it through, which I simply deleted.

I did go ahead and deleted the "com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags" with `xattr -d "com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags" jake` which now leaves me with a trailing +/plus symbol on one of the folders.  Which If I remember, means there are ACL's attached to it.

I was asked for my admin login and password just to move a folder from one place to another, within the same directory area.  I ran `sudo chown -R myusername:staff ~/Documents/friends-backups/jake` which returned no errors, and as far as I can see, all files were changed to a user of my username and a group of staff.  What is still special about these parent directories that require admin permissions just to move them around?  They should be the same as any folder I create. Plus, they came from other drives, should then not inherit my permissions to an extent?  I believe there is even a file that defines what "*newly copied to my system*" files receive as far as permissions.

I am stumped, I should be able to freely move files and directories anywhere ***WITHIN*** my own home folder as long as I have not set some esoteric file permissions, ACLS, or the like to the file(s).  Any suggestions?  My goal here is to get them bundled up in some way, so they are not shooing up in the Mac OS X Find, or the unix `find`.  I know I can exclude them from the Mac OS X Find, and cab be more specific about my paths in `find` or there probably is an exclusion list, it seems so much easier of I just bundle them up into a single file that the OS and it's tool can't easily peek into.

Thank you for any help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The question had been unanswered for so long and I do not know if Jake and Amber now have their files back already, but I will provide an answer anyway.

At first some explanations about things you were puzzled about:

When creating a file using any method fails (Disk Utility in your example), the file will be invalidated (or more commonly known as "deleted") again.  This is nothing unusual.

Copying and moving is the same operation in the background with moving doing a second operation after the copy process, which is deleting the file from its originating location.  In the Finder when moving a file the title of the process window will still say "Copy" while the message inside that same window will say "Move".

Now to actually answering your question:

I do agree that within your own home folder you should never be asked for permissions when handling any file.  So, unless there is indeed a file (or more) which is corrupted (you stated that you are sure that none is), it is a permissions issue.

Permissions in Mac OS X are threefold:

- ownership
- POSIX & Access Control List (ACL) permissions
- file flags

Attributes can also have a play in this, but it is not so common.

To frankly get write access to files again for the sake of copying/moving them, the quickest way is:

1. open Terminal
2. run the following command to reset the ACLs

   ```
   sudo chmod -RN /Users/me/Documents/friends
   ```
3. open your home folder in Finder
4. right-click (or Ctrl-click) the folder "Documents" and click on "Get Info"
5. inside the "Get Info" window, disclose the section "Sharing & Permissions" (if not already displayed to you)
6. click the miniature padlock on the lower right-hand corner and enter your password
7. now click on the button displaying a cogwheel and choose "Apply to enclosed items..."

This will not only apply the same owner, but also the same permissions and ACL to each file below "Documents".  Since all your personal files inside Documents are supposed to already have those permissions, no harm will be done to your own files when doing so.

In case attributes are actually the cause, besides the command you did before on each files, you can also run it recursively or (depending on your system version) clear them entirely.  The latter should be seen with a bit of caution as sometimes attributes are desired on certain files.

To delete just "com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags" from each of Jake's and Amber's files:

```
xattr -d -r com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags /Users/me/Documents/friends
```

To clear attributes entirely:

```
xattr -c -r /Users/me/Documents/friends
```

Since you used command-line, have a look at the other commands for altering permissions:

- chown
- chmod
- chflags

I encourage you to read the man pages for each command before using them in order to avoid improper use ("man chown", "man chmod", "man chflags"), but following are some explanations.

"chown" will change the ownership of a file, but not its permissions.  If you own a file, but have read-only access, you will still be asked for an admin password to temporarily elevate your permissions to "root" for certain operations like moving, editing or deleting.

"chmod" will modify the actual permissions.  Those are either the file permissions known as POSIX permissions or Access Control List entries (ACL entries or ACEs).

"chflags" will change the file flags.